# Does $f_t(x) \to \mbox{sgn}(x)$ as $ t \to 0$ imply $|f_t(x) - \mbox{sgn}(x)|< t$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Define a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as 
>   $$\begin{equation}
>     f_t(x) =
>     \begin{cases}
>        -1 & \text{if}\; \,x<-t \\
>        \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2 t}\right) & \text{if}\;\, |x| \le t\\
>       1       & \text{if}\;\, x>t
>     \end{cases}
>   \end{equation} $$
>   Then $f(x)$ converges pointwise to $\mbox{sgn}(x)$ as $t \to 0$. 
>   I'm wondering if something stronger can be proven, can we say  $|f_t(x) - \mbox{sgn}(x)|< t$ ?

Comment: Do you mean \begin{equation}
    f_t(x) =
    \begin{cases}
       -1 & \text{if}\; \,x<-t \\
       \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2 t}\right) & \text{if}\;\, |x| \le t\\
      1       & \text{if}\;\, x>t
    \end{cases}?
  \end{equation} I.e., $x<-t$ in the first case.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Yes, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an estimate cannot hold. It would imply that  $f_t(x)  \to \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ *uniformly* in $x$, and – since each $f_t$ is a continuous function – that the limit function is continuous as well (which it isn't).

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you want is not true. If $|f_t(x)-sgn(x)|<t$ then, taking $x=\frac t n$ we get $|sin(\frac {\pi} {2n})-1|<t$ for all $n$ which implies $1\leq t$.